# How to get file size from another site src?

Tags: javascript, cors, blob

So, guys, I get src's, from another site, and have the array like `["www.another.com/pic1.png", "www.another2.com/pic2.jpg"]`.

I tested `XMLHttpRequest`, and `file.size`, but CORS does not allow to do it.
How can I get file size, from this array items?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You must to resolve `CORS` problem. so you may can use a `Node.js` server as `web crawler` server to get data from another website.

Then you can use any tool which is can get detail of file to know the file size of the image.